# g_strjoin crashes when joining two strings

Tags: c, glib

I'm joining two simple strings using `glib-2.0`. Here is my code:

```
int main() {

    gchar *a = "12";
    gchar *b = "1231212";

    printf("a: %s\n", a);
    printf("b: %s\n", b);
    gchar *c = g_strjoin(",", a, b);
    printf("c: %s\n", c);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It crashes at `g_strjoin(",", a, b)`. Core file doesn't show much information:

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `./server'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:137
137     FIND_ZERO
```

Am I doing something wrong? I'm using `glib2-2.38.2-2.fc20.x86_64` on fedora 20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `g_strjoin()` can join an arbitrary number of strings, the list has to be terminated with `NULL`:

```
 gchar *c = g_strjoin(",", a, b, NULL );
```